# Call print function inside other function in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 functions, `imprimirPDF()` that prints a range into a PDF and `marcarImpreso()` that marks them as printed in a checkbox in another sheet. I am trying to combine both so that they run together when a button is pressed in the sheet, but it's not working.

I've tried calling `imprimirPDF()` inside `marcarImpreso()`, and calling both in a new one, and the second one works fine, but the printing one only shows the modal dialog that's written into it, it doesn't open the pdf in a new window. When executed on its own it works fine.

I think *maybe* it has to do with the **js.html** file it calls, as that's what makes the PDF open in a new window, but I know very little about coding and scripting so I have no idea how I could solve it so it works.

Here are the scripts:

Imprimir.gs file

```
function imprimirPDF() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange("F3:F").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var range = sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow, 8)

  var PRINT_OPTIONS = {
  'size': 7,               // paper size.  7=A4
  'fzr': false,            // repeat row headers
  'portrait': false,        // false=landscape
  'fitw': true,            // fit window or actual size
  'gridlines': true,      // show gridlines
  'printtitle': false,
  'sheetnames': false,
  'pagenum': 'UNDEFINED',  // CENTER = show page numbers / UNDEFINED = do not show
  'attachment': false,
  'top_margin': 0.5, 
  'bottom_margin': 0.5,
  'left_margin': 0.5,
  'right_margin': 0.5
  }

  var PDF_OPTS =  objectToQueryString(PRINT_OPTIONS); 

  var gid = sheet.getSheetId();
  var printRange = objectToQueryString({
    'c1': range.getColumn() - 1,
    'r1': range.getRow() - 1,
    'c2': range.getColumn() + range.getWidth() - 1,
    'r2': range.getRow() + range.getHeight() - 1
  });

    Logger.log(printRange)

  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 'export?format=pdf' + PDF_OPTS + printRange + "&gid=" + gid;

  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('js');
  htmlTemplate.url = url;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlTemplate.evaluate().setHeight(10).setWidth(100), 'Print range');
}

function objectToQueryString(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return Utilities.formatString('&%s=%s', key, obj[key]);
  }).join('');
}
```

js.html file

```
<script>
  window.open('<?=url?>', '_blank', 'width=800, height=600');
  google.script.host.close();
</script>
```

Marcar Impreso.gs file

```
function marcarImpreso() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetRange = s.getDataRange();
  var sheetValues = sheetRange.getValues();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var rowKeeper = [];
  var rowString = "";

  for (var i=sheetRange.getLastRow()-1; i>1; i--) {
   // si valor en columna D (medio) <> ""
    if ( sheetValues[i][5] != "") {
      rowKeeper.push(i);

      Logger.log(rowKeeper)

    }   
  }
  var response = ui.alert('Se van a marcar los pedidos como IMPRESOS.', rowString, ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  if (response == ui.Button.OK) {
    for (var j = 0; j < rowKeeper.length; j++){
      var i = rowKeeper[j];  
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("*MASTER*");
      var targetRow = sheetValues[i][2];
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetRow, 14);
      var targetTS = targetSheet.getRange(targetRow, 15);

      targetRange.setValue(true); 
      targetTS.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd-mm-yy hh:mm")
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Could you please share a sample of your spreadsheet (*with no sensitive information*) so that we can test on it ? Thanks !

Comment: Could not reproduce at all. You should update the question with how do you try to combine them, it is highly likely that the issue stems from it (no need to share a spreadsheet)

Comment: I added it to a simplified version of my sheet, the relevant sheets are the first two, i put them in pink. I tried to call the print function inside the checkbox function by adding `imprimirPDF();` to it, also tried combining function `myFunction() {  
  imprimirPDF();
  marcarImpreso();
}`. It's clearly calling the function because the dialoge box shows, but it's not opening the pdf. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tzGnuT107u1msx6BchZAEHE7NbsxIVcqXasGilQeTbA/edit?usp=sharing